# How do i avoid reset the timer value on Page Refresh / Page Loading using java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code in which i have use readCookies function but when it's not responding, it shows nothing in the div even alert is also not working.

```
seconds = readCookie('countdown') || 60;
alert(seconds);

function secondPassed() {
    seconds--;
    var minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60);
    var remainingSeconds = parseInt(seconds % 60);
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + parseInt(remainingSeconds);
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + " mins : " + remainingSeconds + " secs";
    if (parseInt(seconds) === 0) {
        alert("Time is over");
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Time is Over";
        document.forms["myForm"].submit();
        document.location.href = "examresult.jsp";
    }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval(function () {
    secondPassed();
    if (seconds === 0) {
        eraseCookie(seconds);
    } else {
        createCookie(seconds, seconds, 7);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: set timer seconds also in cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value in a cookie or browser storage, before page unload and re-load it from cookie or browser storage in page refresh.

For example (pseudo-code):

```
window.onunload = function(){
     set_cookie('timer', timer) /* you need to implement this function */;
}

window.onload = function() {
   timer = get_cookie('timer'); /* you need to implement this function */
   if ( null == timer ) timer = 0; /* not page refresh, start a new timer */
}
```

Comment: please provide me working example for it.. or where should i use the above code, in my function or instead of my function... i think i have done almost in my code but finally it is not responding...

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY, since you have implemented `get_cookie`, `set_cookie` functions (or equivalents) then just add the event handlers for window load and unload so that on unload you store the current timer and on load you restore the current timer (if has been set) else create a new timer. The point is to hook into window `load` and `unload` events to store and restore the current timer, the rest are the same, thus why the pseudo-code